# Loadin background image in codeigniter

Tags: css

I have been trying to load a background image in my html doc but doesn't seem to work. The image resides in an image folder in the same directory as my html doc.I am using codeigniter.
I tried this
  background-image('../image/main.jpg');

please i need help here

Comment: try `background-image('./image/main.jpg');`

Comment: Are you writing PHP or CSS?

Comment: Have you tried Bruce's suggestion? That would be the path I'd be going down.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
background-image:url('../image/main.jpg');
```

Because this is wrong:

```
background-image('../image/main.jpg');
```

Evidence:

[image]

[image]